# rlang::sym doesn't seem to work with the object

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

Why does this statement

```
cols <- map(coln, quo(sym(.)))
```

keeps giving me object  '.' not found?
I have loaded rlang and dplyr.

Comment: are you trying to do something like `cols <- map(coln, ~quo(sym(.x)))`??? which seems weird anyway.

Comment: @Onyambu neither `map(names(iris), ~quo(sym(.)))` nor `map(names(iris), ~quo(sym(.x)))` is outputting any error on my computer.

Comment: @John What exactly is in `coln`? Are you trying something really experimental with quosures? I'm quite curious about what you intend to do with the variable `cols`.

Comment: @DanChaltiel of course it won't throw an error that is why i commented it, but WHY do it? what is the objective?

Comment: I need to put a period as a prefix to a long list of variable names with the object name **coln**

Comment: ... the error message stems from the missing "~" which signals the start of an anonymous function, i.e. `map(coln, ~quo(sym(.)))`

Answer (score 1):

> I need to put a period as a prefix to a long list of variable names with the object name coln

Not 100% sure I understand the goal, but it sounds like a simple string manipulation:

```
# If coln contains variable names as strings
coln <- c("x","y","z")
stringr::str_c( ".", coln )
# [1] ".x" ".y" ".z"

# If coln contains variable names as symbols
coln <- rlang::exprs(x,y,z)
purrr::map( coln, ~rlang::sym(stringr::str_c(".", .x)) )
# [[1]]
# .x
# 
# [[2]]
# .y
# 
# [[3]]
# .z
```